# Linked list of different classes - in a maintanable way?

Tags: c++

Yo people,

My problem is, I have to find a way to easily maintain the next situation:
I have a linked list of different classes. I use void pointers, every class has "int type" as its first member.

Now when I want to call a class member function, I have to do this:
- Read the int, so I know the type of the class.
- I call a generic function with the type information, and also the "function" information to know which class member function to call.

So its basically a switch case in a switch case like this:

```
void command(void *&pointer, int type, int function)
   {
   switch (type)
      {
      case 1:
      switch (function)
         {
         case 1:
         reinterpret_cast<myClass *>(pointer)->doSomething();
         }
      }

   }
```

I do not even know what to do when a function, like "doSomething()" will need some arguments.

And it is a total mess anyway. I am sure there is a better way than this, but do not know what is it.

Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: Is this an actual problem you're trying to solve or a theoretical one? Because it is hairy and unpleasant and no answer, not even a `boost`-based one, is gonna be fun. (Well, maybe a `boost`-based one.)

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: It is an actual one, mate.

Comment: I was worried about that. Have fun. :P

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan :D. Thanks for the encouragement. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself writing code like "if A is of type X, then do something, and if it's of type Y, then do something else", then you are likely to be able to use polymorphism: introduce an abstract base class for those.

You would then have the list of objects of that abstract base class, and on each object you'd call a virtual method. Each class would implement it in its own way, so no `case` and casting would be neccessary. This is usually the best solution.

However, the only thing I can tell you without you describing your situation in more detail is: *"Rethink your class design, as you're likely to have some logical mistakes there and your problem may be the consequence of those".*

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html) were specifically invented so you don't have to switch over types.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::list`, from the header `<list>`.

Or it may actually be that some other container may be more suitable, but you don't provide details of your problem.

Anyway, when you as a beginner feel the need to use `void*`, then you know that you're doing something Very Wrong™ – don't.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

If your list of possible container element types is limited (as seems likely given the type -> value mapping you plan to use), you could implement a container of [Boost Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.motivation).  This would be preferable to the brute force type -> value mapping and casting that you currently expect to need.

Without knowing more about what the objects DO, it's hard to be sure that this would work, though.